# How to query collection using cypher in neo4j?

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have one node in neo4j whose structure looks like:

```
{
            "nodeId": 32,
            "id": "0290cf88-3345-4c30-8e5f-7ce0cb3f0b6b",
            "type": "User",
            "name": "Mahendra",
            "index": 0,
            "data": "This is sample user",
            "description": null,
            "contentBlocks": [],
            "icon": null,
            "createdOn": null,
            "modifiedOn": null,
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Mahendra",
                "lastName": "Kawde"
            },
            "tags": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ],
            "categories": null
        }
```

Now I want to get all nodes by passing tags as a parameter to my cypher query.
I am using below query:

```
MATCH (node) WHERE node.tags = ['tag1','tag2'] RETURN node
```

This returns me all nodes with given tags.
But if I use below query

```
MATCH (node) WHERE node.tags = ['tag1'] RETURN node
```

it does not return me any node.

Also if I change the order lets say ['tag2','tag1'] it does not returns me any node.

Below is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getByTag",method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
    public Result<Node> getByTag(@RequestParam(value="tags") List<String> tags) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return nodeService.getByTag(tags);
    }
```

Service method:

```
public Result<Node> getByTag(List<String> tags) {

        HashMap params = new HashMap();
        params.put("type",tags);

        String query = "MATCH (node) WHERE node.tags = "+ tags +" RETURN node";

        Result<Node> nodes = neo4jTemplate.query(query, params).to(Node.class);
        return nodes;   
    }
```

Can you give me a way to use collection, more precisely `List<String>` in cypher query ?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
MATCH (node) 
WHERE ALL (x IN ['tag1','tag2'] WHERE x in node.tags)
RETURN node
```

See http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/query-predicates.html

Comment: Yes it working.
But what If I add another tag lets say like this : WHERE ALL (x IN ['tag1','tag2','tag3'] WHERE x in node.tags)

Comment: Then it does not returns any node

Comment: ALL will make sure that the node matched has every tag supplied in the list. If you want some to match, then use another variation from the link above such as ANY

Comment: can you please tell me how to add pagination to my query